# Find maximum amount of gold that can can be collected from a grid

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Given a grid of m*n size. Each block in grid has some amount of gold.

We start from first column of the grid(any row) and we can move only in 3 direction - right, right-up(left diagonal) and right-down(right diagonal).

What is the maximum amount of gold we can collect from the grid.

I have tried using Dynamic Programming with below recurrence relation

dp[i][j]=max{a[i-1][j+1],a[i][j+1],a[i+1][j+1]} +a[i][j] for j= 0 to n-1
and dp[i][j]=0 for i<0 or i>=m

Does this will give correct and optimal answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

```
d[i][j]
```

be the maximum amout of gold which can be obtained by starting from position `(i,j)` by moving only right, right-up and right-down, for any `i in [0..m-1]`, `j in [0..n-1]`. We obtain the following recurrence relation, which is meant to be read in the senese that access to coordinates outside of `[0..m-1]` and `[0..n-1]` are meant to return `0`.

```
d[i][j] = a[i][j] + max { d[i  ][j+1], // right
                          d[i-1][j+1], // right up
                          d[i+1][j+1]  // right down
                        }
```

The problem here is to use a sequence of evaluation for which every needed value of `d` occurring in the `max` expression is available for evaluation of `d[i][j]`. The sequence for evaluation must start at the rightmost column by setting `d[i][n-1] = a[i][n-1]` for each `i in [0..m-1].` The states have to filled column-wise from right to left; after evaluation, the optimum amount of gold is the maximum value occuring in the leftmost column.

Comment: If two of the moves are right-up and right-down, I'd expect to see a minus sign in there somewhere.

Comment: Why can't you start at the top-right corner, or anywhere in the rightmost column?

Comment: @ScottHunter You can; my explanation was totally misleading, I hope it is fixed by now,

Comment: Since you can start in any row, the optimum may *not* be in `d[0][0]`.